# How to determine binary relevances based on continuos model ouputs

Tags: recommender-system

Consider the following dataset

search_id, features, binary_relevance

I have trained a ranking model, but it predicts continuos ranks. How do i binarize them? I know that within each search id I could determine the best binarization threshold based on ROC, but how do i determine the threshold for an entire model.